# jQuery-UI sortable: Animate from original position to new after helper drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

**TLDR**

I want to be able to animate my jQuery-UI sortable after the helper has been dropped by showing the original item moving to it's new position with the others shifting around. This is complicated by certain sortables needing to be fixed in position.

**The Project:**

The project involves dynamically generated jQuery-UI portlets within a tabbed interface. The tabs and portlet contents themselves are generated through async AJAX requests to established web services. Each tab has an undetermined number of portlets within it, and uses custom scrollbars for content display. I have implemented the fixing of certain portlets using classes and a solution found elsewhere on stack overflow (slightly modified). A very basic implementation of current functionality can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/99yVq/.

**The Problem**

Prior to implementing portlet fixing I was animating while sorting by showing and hiding the placeholder element:

```
$( ".content" ).sortable({       
    start: function(e, ui){
        $(ui.placeholder).hide(300);
    },
    change: function (e,ui){
        $(ui.placeholder).hide().show(300);
    }
});
```

Viewable in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/BWNE2/. This works fairly well but I feel the animation is choppy and it will obviously require some poking to get it to work with the portlet fixing solution above (as it relies on helper creation to determine fixed positions). It is not the solution I'm looking for.

*Update*

Did the poking to combine the two (none was really needed with a caveat) and the combined functionality is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/BWNE2/1/. The animations work but as you can see the .fixed portlet animates along with the others and then reverts back to it's original position.

*End of Update*

**The Question**

My ideal scenario would be for the user to drag the portlet helper (which I believe is a clone of the original item used during dragging) from its original position to it's new one. At the point of dropping the portlets would then animate from there old positions to the new. The current movement during sorting should be maintained to give the end user feedback, but the final animations should take place after the drop of the helper.

Does anyone have any ideas or examples of how to achieve this?

If my question format is inadequate or you require more information on anything please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

*Edit*

You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/BWNE2/2/ that the animation effect is even more inadequate when the fixed portlet it in position 3 (top right of the top section). It is often not in the correct position while sorting, though it does revert to the correct place on sort end.

Comment: No ideas or do I need to clarify the question?

Comment: So yeah I'm not sure I understand completely what your going for.. So even though when you drag it animates (shuffles the the portlets around) when you drop the portlet you want it to show up back where it started and then animate over to where it was dropped?

Comment: Honestly I don't understand what the problem is. Can you specify your question in one or two sentences? Why is http://jsfiddle.net/BWNE2/ not a good solution? Seems to work fine. :)

Comment: As a solution it works, however it is not the functionality I want. As @Trevor states I want the portlet to smoothly animate from it's starting position to it's new position after the helper has been dropped. I'm attempting to find an example now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the solution found [in other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060357/jquery-sortable-with-animation), which is basically when dragging you clone the itens and animate them to the new positions, I merged that into your code.

What this code didn't had was the animation after the release, which i made by saving the position on the `mouseup` event, and animating the dragged element to the final position.

Final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hTgad/

Code:

```
var lastPosition;

$( "#content" ).sortable({
    delay: 100,
    distance: 10,
    handle: '.portlet-header',
    items: '.portlet:not(.fixed)',
    start: function(e, ui)
    {
        //store the fixed itens position
        $('.fixed', this).each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.data('pos', $this.index());
        });

        // Identify the item being dragged
        ui.helper.addClass("being-dragged");

        var clonedItems = $("#cloned_items");

        // Create a clone for every item, except the fixed ones and the one being dragged            
        $("#content .portlet:not(.being-dragged, .ui-sortable-placeholder, .fixed)").each(function(){
            // clone the original items to make their
            // absolute-positioned counterparts...
            var original = $(this);
            var clone = original.clone();
            // 'store' the clone for later use...
            original.data("clone", clone);
            original.css("visibility", "hidden"); // Hide the original

            // set the initial position of the clone
            var position = original.position();
            clone.css("left", position.left)
                 .css("top", position.top);

            // append the clone...
            clonedItems.append(clone);
        });
    },
    change: function(e,ui) 
    {
        //change the position of the fixed elements to the original one
        $sortable = $(this);
        $statics = $('.fixed', this).detach();
        $helper = $('<div class="portlet" style="background-color:#000"></div>').prependTo(this);
        $statics.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var target = $this.data('pos');
            $this.insertAfter($('.portlet', $sortable).eq(target));
        });
        $helper.remove();

        // animate all clones to the new position
        $("#content .portlet:not(.being-dragged, .ui-sortable-placeholder, .fixed)").each(function(){
            var item = $(this);
            var clone = item.data("clone");

            // stop current clone animations...
            clone.stop(true, false);

            var position = item.position(); // New position
            clone.animate({left: position.left, top:position.top}, 500);
        });

    },

    stop: function(e, ui){
        var el = $("#content .being-dragged");
        // Save the new position
        var newPosition = el.position();
        // Insert a placeholder for the final animation
        $('<div class="portlet ui-sortable-placeholder"></div>').insertBefore(el);
        el.css("left", lastPosition.left)
          .css("top", lastPosition.top)
          .css("position", "absolute")
          .animate({left: newPosition.left, top: newPosition.top}, 300, "swing", function() {
              // After the animation remove the placeholder and reset the element position
              $("#content .ui-sortable-placeholder").remove();
              $(this).css("left", "").css("top", "").css("position", "");
          })
          .removeClass("being-dragged");

        // Erase the temporary itens
        $("#cloned_items").empty();

        // make sure all our original items are visible again...
        $("#content .portlet").css("visibility", "visible");
    }

});

// Save the position of the element being dragged for the final animation
$(".portlet").on("mouseup", function() {
    lastPosition = $(this).position();
});
```

Comment: While this isn't exactly what I was looking for (animation occurs real time rather than after the fact) it is a far better solution than my original attempt, and the animations are silky smooth. Very well done.

Comment: animating all panels after the mouse up wouldnt be nice, they would have to go back to their original position and animate to the final ones. it would work if there were no feedback while dragging, but i think the way i did is better.

Comment: I think you might be right, and I love the animations in your solution. Unfortunately I am trying to emulate existing functionality.

Comment: i don't know exactly what you want, but you can adapt this code. for instance, you can animate the clones to their final position on `stop`  (iterate through original itens, save/reset position, animate)